onbeforeunload event not trigger on window object inside iframe when iframe is removed programatically
This is the parent page where iframe is added: When trying to call the remove method on parent page, the onbeforeunload is not getting fired.
However when adding the onunload event it is getting triggered. I want to add some cleanup script before iframe removal for that i am using onbeforeunload.
Is it a bug on html side that onbeforeunload is not getting fired when it is getting removed from the document.
Help needed.
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
        console.log("Main window ==========> ", window);
        console.log(window === window.top);
        function removeIframe() {
            const iframe = document.getElementById("iframe1");
            document.body.removeChild(iframe);
        }
        window.addEventListener("beforeunload", () => {
            localStorage.setItem("mainwindow", "Removed window");
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Main windows</p>
    <iframe src="./temp1.html" id="iframe1">
    </iframe>
    <button onclick="removeIframe()">Delete</button>
    
</body>
</html>


This is the code for iframe where the code for the iframe

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script>
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        console.log('before unload');
    }
    console.log("Iframe window ======> ", window);
    console.log(window === window.top);
</script>
<body>
    <p>Inside iframe</p>
</body>
</html>

